# Combining values for duplicate indexes in array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to combine the values for duplicate indexes. For example, I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Player1
            [1] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Player2
            [1] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Player1
            [1] => 50
        )
)
```

`Player1` appears twice in the array so I need to remove the second occurrence but  add the value `50` to the  first occurence. Like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Player1
            [1] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Player2
            [1] => 10
        )
)
```

Is there any existing php function that I can do this with?

Comment: There are a lot of [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) in PHP and several of them can be used to get the expected result but they also require writing some code. But in the end, a simple [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) that uses [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) and a couple of assignments can do the job without much fuss. It takes less to write it than you needed to write this question.

Comment: This must be a horrible array to work with. Why not have player as the key for the value? `$arr= ["player1" => 100]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regular `foreach` loop and `array_values` function:

```
$arr = [
    ['Player1', 50], ['Player2', 10], ['Player1', 50],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $k = $item[0];
    (isset($result[$k]))? $result[$k][1] += $item[1] : $result[$k] = $item;
}
$result = array_values($result);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Player1
            [1] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Player2
            [1] => 10
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try PHP `in_array()` function to check if that element exists or not by doing something like this

```
 if (in_array("Player1", $arrayname))
  {
  echo "Match found"; // do match and replace here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like create `Player` class with `equal()` and `addPints()` methods can be possible way to go. It will encapsulate comparison of objects

```
<?php
class Player {
    /** @var int **/
    private $points;

    /** @var string **/
    private $name;

    public function __construct(string $name, int $points) 
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->points = $points;
    }

    public function equals(Player $player) : bool
    {
        return $this->name === $player->name();
    }

    public function name() : string 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function points() : int
    {
        return $this->points;
    }

    public function addPoints(int $points) : void
    {
        $this->points += $points;
    }
}

$a1 = [new Player("player1", 50), new Player("player2", 10), new Player("player1", 50)];

$result = [];

foreach ($a1 as $player) {
    $existing = false;

    foreach ($result as $player2) {
        if ($player2->equals($player)) {
            $player2->addPoints($player->points());
            $existing = true;
        }

    }

    if (!$existing) {
        $result[] = $player;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative output array is to have the "player" as the key in the array and the value being the score.
I find this a more efficient array and easier to work with.
Instead of having a generic number prior to each player
`echo $arr[5][0]; // example "Player7"`
And then you need to get the value with:
`echo $arr[5][1]; // example "50"`
which is rather hard to use.
My answer gives you
`echo $arr["Player7"]; // "50"`.

This answer does not meet expected result, but may be useful for others.

```
$arr = [['Player1', 50], ['Player2', 10], ['Player1', 50]];

Foreach($arr as $subarray){
    // If player does not exist in result array add it with zero score.
    If(!isset($result[$subarray[0]])) $result[$subarray[0]]=0;

    // Add current player score to result array player score.
    $result[$subarray[0]] +=$subarray[1];
} 
Var_dump($result);
```

Output;

```
array(2) {
    ["Player1"]=> int(100)
    ["Player2"]=> int(10)
}
```